# Is there any possible way to add a bitmap to the property sheet footer?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

At present I am working on the property sheet in mfc ,and this property sheet was set to PS_WIZARD97 style.As we know that  property sheet of this style consists of header and footer .Now I got a scenario to add a bitmap to the footer.As we don't have control over the property sheet I am little bit confused how to add bitmap to the footer.

Note:Footer-The place in the property sheet where we have  [Back]-[Next]-[Cancel] buttons.

Does any way exist to draw the bitmap on the footer of the property sheet?

Can anyone please let me know if there exists way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried deriving your own class from CPropertySheet?  You would then have complete control over all aspects, including rendering of images, of the property sheet.

Comment: Since CPropertySheet is derived from CWnd, you can take advantage of the methods and messages exposed from CWnd.  Start first, by seeing if the message handler for [OnEraseBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz.aspx) suits your needs.

Comment: OnEraseBackground receives a pointer to a device context.  You can use the device context to perform your rendering.

Comment: @rrirower ,as I told you I am very new to mfc,I did not understand how we render image to the footer using CDC.I am will be very grateful to you if you could help to explain how can we render image on the footer.How exactly we can get the co-ordinates of the footer.

Comment: using spy++ when I placed the mouse on the footer separator of the property sheet it is showing handle as 001E0636 ,I am just asking whether this will be helpful to me or not .

Comment: Knowing the handle is not helpful. It will have a different value the next time the program is run. The replies from @rrirower are the way to proceed. Learn how to derive a class and add the OnEraseBackground message handler. Paint in that function.

Comment: Derived a class from CPropertySheet and added OnEraseBackground and I am newbie to mfc.As per my knowledge ,if we want to paint the bitmap width and height can be retrieved,now if we want to paint it on the footer how do we know the co-ordinates of the footer.If possible can you please give me an example how can we paint on the footer,something like this I tried in OnEraseBackGround
CPaintDC dc(this);
pDC->CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
CBitmap bm;
bm.LoadBitmap(m_nBitmap);
pDC->SelectObject(bm);
CRect rc;
GetClientRect(&rc);
dc.BitBlt(0,0,rc.Width(), rc.Height(), pDC, 0,0,SRCCOPY);